# Highlight the word in ppt using python-pptx

Tags: text, python-pptx

I want to read ppt and highlight certain word(background color added if background color is not possible then change the font color) in the slide. I am able to do it at sentence level i.e. if that word is contain in paragraph then it will change the font color of whole text but i want to change the color of that word only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following for highlighting?

```
def set_highlight(run, color):
    # get run properties
    rPr = run._r.get_or_add_rPr()

    # Create highlight element
    hl = OxmlElement("a:highlight")

    # Create specify RGB Colour element with color specified
    srgbClr = OxmlElement("a:srgbClr")
    setattr(srgbClr, "val", color)

    # Add colour specification to highlight element
    hl.append(srgbClr)

    # Add highlight element to run properties
    rPr.append(hl)

    return run
```

It's hacking the XML but for highlighting (text background) that's what you have to do.